Falla Carga de Imagen Gitthub Pages
Resulta que crie un repositorio, y no consigo la forma de que mis imágenes se visualizan, cuando abro el archivo Index.html, las imágenes se visualizan, pero cuando abro el repositorio desde Gitbuh no abre, conforme a las imágenes enviadas en archivos adjuntos.
Espero sus recomendaciones.
Intentéis agregar el archivo galería, mejores sus recomendaciones.
Esta es la dirección de mi repositorio: https://github.com/Josue552/Energia-Solar-con-Josu-

No se entiende el problema. ¿Que se supone que debo hacer para "abrir el repositorio desde GitHub"? ¿Que URL debo escribir en mi browser?

la imagen en mi repositorio no cargan

Normalmente en GitHub lo que se despliega (con imagenes) es el archivo Readme.md, no el index.html. El readme.md es un archivo con markup, no con html.
